# How to open a file in Qt-method but read it use C-language function?

Tags: qt

I know Qt has a lot of good methods for reading file.But in my work , I have to open a file by using Qt and get a pointer pointing to the start address of the file.So how to do that?

Here is my codes:

```
char *buffer; 
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
            {
            QByteArray dataArray=file.readAll();
            buffer=dataArray.data();
        } 

char test[1024];    
for(int i=0;i<1024;i++)
        {
            test[i]=*buffer;
            buffer++;
        }
```

I use `QByteArray QIODevice::​readAll()`to read all available data from the device, and returns it as a byte array.

Then I use `char * QByteArray::​data()` to set my pointer `buffer`.

But when I try to read the data by a for loop,my Qt debugger throw me an `error:read access violation`,so how would this happen?

BTW , the file to be read is very big so I can't use a buffer to read them all once. Instead , I have to do as what I did here. When I read a 7kb-sizes-file ,my codes runs well. When I read a 700kb-sizes-file , here comes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting access violation is that `dataArray` is declared inside `if` code block and goes out of scope. You want to declare the `dataArray` outside of that block, eg:

```
QByteArray dataArray;
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    dataArray = file.readAll();
}
else
{
    // give error
}

char *buffer = dataArray.data();

char test[1024]; 
for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
{
    test[i] = *buffer;
    buffer++;
}
```

There are other potential problems in your code though:

First, what if the size of data read from the file is less than 1024? Then you will be reading past the end of the buffer (more access violations).

Second, what if the file is really big? Reading all that data at once may cause swapping/paging.